# Как добавить описание товара в платежной системе liqpay в телеграмм боте (что написать в provider_data)?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, liqpay

api liqpay: https://www.liqpay.ua/documentation/api/home - не описывает как  добавить описание к платежу в боте .
Есть ссылка на пример от yookassa: https://yookassa.ru/docs/support/payments/onboarding/integration/cms-module/telegram
[image: пример yookassa]
Что нужно написать в provider_data чтоб появилось любое описание квитанции (телефон, email... )
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.